# Reload the page on button click in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I am making an accounting software using Netbeans and MySQL.
I need to reload the page on a button click.
As in, the page takes entry for a product. When Add button is clicked, the entry should go into the database and the JFrame that takes the entry should be reloaded to take next entry.
The entry gets entered into the database but the reloading fails and the project needs to be rerun in order to upload next entry.

The entry system takes an input from a combo box and 10 other text boxes. On clicking the add button, the entries get added to the databas and all the fields are reset. Indeed. But the problem is, now the fields arent editable anymore.

revalidate() and repaint() aren't working.
What other options are there ?

Comment: Please provide us with a [SCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) and/or an image of what your entry system looks like. What elements exactly do you need "reloaded to take [the] next entry?"

Comment: I cannot yet upload an image, but the components of the frame are labels, a combobox, a few text boxes and a few buttons.

Comment: You know that a Swing application is not a web application right? There are no pages to reload. Netbeans has absolutely nothing to do with it either. If you want the values of the components in the GUI to change (probably become empty in this case), then write the code that changes them. If you need help fixing a problem, post the code and any errors you are getting.

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example of your problem, it will help reduce the guess work and provide better solutions

Comment: By page I meant a JFrame. 
I did initialize the fields. They arent editable anymore

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: You should still provide code as the answer I posted should still be able to clear your text fields and combo boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the `JTextField` text elements after clicking the button and change the selected indexes for the `JComboBox` elements. For instance, in your button's `ActionListener`:

```
tfTextField.setText("");
cbComboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
```

Comment: I did all of that !
The fields are initialised too. But the problem is, they are no more editable.

Comment: @Krithi Read my comment on your original post and share the relevant code as a [SCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I made the changes in the original post. See if it helps provide details

Answer (score 0):

```
this.dispose();
JFrame f = new Add();
f.setVisible(true);
```

This did it. 
The form gets disposed and then it loads again.